# Spring Boot Zuul: How to register multiple MS in discovery service without app prefix

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

Let's say I have 2 MicroServices:

```
ms-1
ms-2
```

ms-1 has REST service GET /api/myService1
ms-2 has REST service GET /api/myService2

I have them both register in Spring Boot discovery service (Eureka) and integrated with Zuul as the gateway, so they are auto-mapped as:

```
/ms-1/api/myService1
/ms-2/api/myService2
```

This is working OK, no problem, but I want the microservices registered in the discovery service to be available in Zuul without the application name prefix, so in my example, they would be available as:

```
/api/myService1
/api/myService2
```

(No App name in the path)

Is this possible with Eureka discovery service (no yaml configuration pamming each path but just using the automatic discovery service by Eureka? How to do it?

Comment: You can try exploring the PatternServiceRouteMapper that might help you or just zuul.stripPrefix: false might do the trick. Read the https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Answer (score 0):

I only have settings for my `Consul` service discovery inside the `bootstrap.yml` file and everything works fine as you want in your question.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-sample
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: true
      host: localhost
```

I guess you just need to tell your zuul application how to find your eurika. And do it exactly in `bootstrap.yml`, not `application.yml`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Zuul routes based on instance IDs from Discovery.

Add this lines to your zuul.properties

```
zuul.routes.ms1.path=/api/myService1
zuul.routes.ms1.service-id=ms-1

zuul.routes.ms2.path=/api/myService2
zuul.routes.ms2.service-id=ms-2
```

then invoke your service with : `https://your_zuul.com/api/myService1`

Comment: Thanks but this is what I need to avoid, having to manual configure every service, and so I am using discovery service (Eureka). The routes are not configured in any .properties or .yaml file.

Comment: @icordoba what you want is avoid the zull configuration in *.yml ?

Comment: Thanks. I already have no Zull configuration in .yml as I use Eureka discovery. What I want to do is get to the configuration requested but using the auto discovery service, not mapping the routes in a yaml file.

Comment: In the approach described above there is still Eureka service discovery being used: ms-1 as well as ms-2 are discovered by Eureka automatically. If you want to change the default routes - you do need to specify somewhere your custom behavior, thus you need to touch config file.